# TypeError: 'estates' is an invalid keyword argument for Estate

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Got a new problem I changed every variable. Got a problem with relationships, and inserting them into the database. I am a little bit confused about what to put on the routes.py at the upload_estate function
Here are some new changes

models.py

```
class Estate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    quarter = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    street = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    bedroom = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    bathroom = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    kitchen = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    livingroom = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('type.id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    estat_type = db.relationship('Type', backref=db.backref('estates', lazy=True))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    image_file_one = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    image_file_two = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    image_file_three = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    image_file_four = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    image_file_five = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Estate %r>' % self.quarter

class Type(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Type %r>' % self.name
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/admin/upload-estate', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def upload_estate():
    form = UploadEstateForm()
    form.type.choices = [(type.id, type.name) for type in Type.query.all()]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_file_one = files.save(request.files.get('image_file_one'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        image_file_two = files.save(request.files.get('image_file_two'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        image_file_three = files.save(request.files.get('image_file_three'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        image_file_four = files.save(request.files.get('image_file_four'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        estate = Estate(
            title=form.title.data,
            quarter=form.quarter.data,
            street=form.street.data,
            price=form.price.data,
            bathroom=form.bathroom.data,
            bedroom=form.bedroom.data,
            livingroom=form.livingroom.data,
            kitchen=form.kitchen.data,
            estates=form.estate_type.data,
            user_id=current_user.id,
            description=form.description.data,
            author=current_user.username,
            image_file_one=image_file_one,
            image_file_two=image_file_two,
            image_file_three=image_file_three,
            image_file_four=image_file_four
        )
        db.session.add(estate)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Estate uploaded successfully!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    return render_template('upload_estate.html', title='Upload Estate', form=form)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error should be self-explanatory. The `Estate` model has no column `estates`. But you are trying to update this imaginary column with `estates=form.estate_type.data`. You should be able to fix the problem by removing the mentioned line, but this may not achieve your desired result in the end. If so, would you mind expounding on the relationship between the `Type` and the `Estate` models?

Comment: The relationship between the Type and Estate models is a one-to-many relationship. I inserted data in the Type table with columns 'id' and 'name' in my database. I am trying to insert data from the Type table to the Estate table via SelectField of wtforms

Comment: Your question format is very personal and not searchable or reproducible because estate is not a programming term and your question is not about a programming problem but your problem while programming. This kind of questions will get few attention and some flags.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that each `Type` table will have multiple estates? As in, each estate will also have only one type?

Comment: Yes, and am sorry if my question seems to be personal

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way your models are set up would indicate that you want one Estate with multiple Types. As this is not the case, I would suggest moving the 'estat_type' column from the `Estates` model into the `Type` one. You would also need to modify it as follows:

```
estat_type = db.relationship('Estate', backref=db.backref('type', lazy=True))
```

This will allow you to access the type of an estate by using the backref 'type' as in `Estate.type`. You can also access all the estates under one type with `Type.estat_type`. (I would recommend changing 'estat_type' to 'estates' as it now holds a list of estates under one type.)

As for updating the tables (if I understand you correctly), the relationships will take care of themselves and you won't need to insert data from the 'Type' table to the 'Estate' table as the type information should be accessible via the backref, `Estate.type`.